# Can I pass parameter to inlude function?

Tags: php, include

I need to pass parameter to include function in php, so suppose to have this:

```
<?php include('template.php'); ?>
```

In `template.php` I want pass parameters something like this:

```
$param=...
$param1=..
 <?php include('template.php',$param,$param1); ?>
```

I don't know if this is the correct way. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Any variables in scope are automatically available in included files - think of it as pulling in the code *from* the included template rather than having to pass variables *into* it.

Comment: You don't need to pass those parameters. Just set those variables before the include statement and those variables will also be accessible in the included file.